# Do we have Asynchronous and Synchronous Latches in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

As we know, there are two types of 'flops' namely Asynchronous(reset) and Synchronous(reset).
Similarly, do we have 'latches' with types Asynchronous and Synchronous?
If yes, how do we model them using a Verilog code?

Comment: There are no latches nor flops in verilog. There are syntactic elements which allow expressing certain aspects of hardware behavior. As a result, there are ways to model behaviors of different types of hardware devices, such as flops, latches, muxes, ... So, if you know how your latch should behave, you can express its behavior in verilog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms *asynchronous* and *synchronous* are relative terms to a clock or some other synchronizing_ signal. A latch only has an *enable* or *load* signal, so there is nothing for it to be synchronized to, and those terms do not apply.

By the way, this question is more suited to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.